# returning json data from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

My Colmodel in javascript looks like this

```
jQuery("#testGrid").jqGrid(

//Some code

colModel: [
 { name: 'field1',index: 'field1', width: 113, align: 'Center', formatter: selectCheckboxFormatter, sortable: false },
{ name: 'field2', index: 'field2', width: 113, align: 'Center' },
{ name: 'field3', index: 'field3', width: 120, align: 'left' }
];

)
```

and my javascript for datasource look as follows. I call this function at some point in my javascript to populate the grid.

```
function PopulateDummyData() {
var mydata = [
{ field1: "Yes", field2: "1", field3: "54555464"},
{ field1: "No", field2: "2", field3: "54555464"},
];
}
```

but I want to get the data in the above function from the controller code, such that the controller action returns a JSON data in the above format, which I can use to populate my grid. and the controller code will be invoked by the grid's URL action using the following code snippet in javascript.

url: UrlAction('MyController', 'PopulateDummyData').

But I am not sure about how the controller code should be? any thoughts or comments??

Comment: What controller are you talking about? Did you mean to tag this question with other languages such as ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @The Matt - Agreed, it would be helpful if there was more information provided, such as the MVC framework that is being used (if one).

Comment: Yes its the asp .net MVC framework that I am talking about. and how would I accept the answers?

Comment: You can accept one answer per question, so for the answer that solved your problem or was the most helpful, click the checkmark that shows up underneath the voting arrows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [some blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813151408/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx):

```
public JsonResult GetStateList() {
  var list = new List<ListItem>() {
    new ListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "VA" },
    new ListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "MD" },
    new ListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "DC" }
  };
  return this.Json(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jqGrid documentation on how to load from an AJAX source..
this is how i did it getting the data from httphandler

> ```
> jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
>             url: 'example.ashx', //this url points to where the data comes from
>             datatype: 'xml',  //this is the data type, can be JSON etc etc              
>             mtype: 'GET',
>             colNames: ['Name', 'Email', 'Archive'],
>             colModel: [
>             { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200,editable:true},
>             { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 250, editable: true },
>             { name: 'Archive', index: 'Archive', width: 80, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: "checkbox",value: "True:False" }
>             ],
>             pager: jQuery('#pager'),
>             rowNum: 5,
>             rowList: [5,10,15,20],
>             sortname: 'id',
>             sortorder: "desc",
>             viewrecords: true,
>             imgpath: '/jqGrid-3.5.alfa/themes/lightness/images',
>             caption: 'My first grid'
>         }).navGrid("#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false,refresh:false,search:false });
>     });
> ```

then my httphandler code looks like

> public String GenerateGrid(HttpContext context, List lstData)
>       {
>           context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
>           string xml = "" + page + " + totalpages + "" + "" + count + "";

```
    List<customObject> temp = lstData.Skip((page - 1) * limit).Take(limit).ToList();

    foreach (var tempOBJ in temp)
    {
        xml += "<row id='" + tempOBJ.id+ "'>";
        xml += "<cell>" + tempOBJ.name+ "</cell>";
        xml += "<cell>" + tempOBJ.lastname + "</cell>";
        xml += "<cell>" + tempOBJ.email + "</cell>";
        xml += "</row>";
    }
    xml += "</rows>";

    return xml;
}
```